# How to retrieve custom product attributes through product description or short description using phtml templates?

Tags: attributes, custom, phtml

Using: Magento 2.4.5 Community Edition

I currently have two custom phtml blocks {short_description.phtml, description.phtml} located in `app/code/Vendor/Theme/view/frontend/templates.`

As an example, short_description.phtml contains:

```
<div class="container attribute-container">
 <div class="attribute-row">
  <div class="col-12">
    <div class="attribute-label">Attribute Label<span style="color #4361ee;">Attribute Value</span>
    </div>
    <div class="attribute-label">Attribute Label<span style="color: #4361ee;">Attribute Value</span>
    </div>
    <div class="attribute-label">Attribute Label<span style="color: #4361ee;">Attribute Value</span>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

On the product page content tab, I am calling these phtml templates using the page builder for short description and description using the following:

```
{{block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" template="Vendor_Theme::short_description.phtml"}}

{{block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" template="Vendor_Theme::description.phtml"}}
```

At the moment, the product pages load the static html content perfectly fine. However, I would like to display the custom product attributes and their labels dynamically.

How would I accomplish this?

**Attempt #1 - Unsuccessful**

- Under storefront properties, the attributes are set to "Yes" for "Used in Product Listing."

I changed the short_description.phtml template to include:

```
<?php 
$product = $block->getProduct(); 
$sku = $product->getAttributeName('sku'); 
$manufacturer = $product->getAttributeName('manufacturer');
$warranty = $product->getAttributeName('warranty');
?>
<div class="container attribute-container">
 <div class="attribute-row">
  <div class="col-12">
    <div class="attribute-label"><?php echo $sku ?><span style="color #4361ee;">Attribute Value</span>
    </div>
    <div class="attribute-label"><?php echo $manufacturer?><span style="color: #4361ee;">Attribute Value</span>
    </div>
    <div class="attribute-label"><?php echo $warranty ?><span style="color: #4361ee;">Attribute Value</span></div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

The error:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eZ47j.png

I realize that I need to call the attribute values with a different function/line of code but I can't seem to get just the attribute labels to display.

Comment: Did you try $product = $block->getProduct();, $product->getAttributeName(); in relevant .phtml file

Comment: Yes, Inside the phtml file I attempted <?php 
$product = $block->getProduct();
$sku = $product->getAttributeName('sku');
?>, then tried calling for the sku in the static content with <?php echo $sku ?> but then the product page turns gray and says an exception has occurred.

Comment: show under product listing is enabled for sku attribute

Comment: Please update the question with your created attribute and error message. Easy to find a sollution.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I have edited to provide all information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi Please see the below answer for more detailed information about how to get the custom product attribute label and values using attribute code and product sku using Attribute Repository.

1. First you need to connect your PHTML file with view model to use the PHP logic as you are calling your PHTML file from a static block , you would have called your template PHTML file in the static block, as of now Block file  can be used as below

   {{block class="OX\PrintSampleContent\Block\Template" template="OX_PrintSampleContent::short_description.phtml"}}

   {{block class="OX\PrintSampleContent\Block\Template" template="OX_PrintSampleContent::description.phtml"}}
2. Register a module and , In your Block PHP file this your logic to get the label and value , please see the code below and you can use it for your reference:

Paste the below code in this path inside your module = app/code/OX/PrintSampleContent/Block/Template.php

```
    <?php

    namespace OX\PrintSampleContent\Block;

    class Template extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
    {
    public $attributeRepository;
    public $productRepository;

    public $productModel = null;

    public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
    \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository,
    \Magento\Eav\Model\AttributeRepository $attributeRepository,
    array $data = []
    ) {
    $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
    $this->attributeRepository = $attributeRepository;
    Parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    public function getLabel($attributeCode)
    {
    if ($this->productModel !== null) {
        $attribute = $this->attributeRepository->get("4", 
        $attributeCode);
        $label = $attribute->getDefaultFrontendLabel();
        return $label;
     }
     return null;
     }

     public function setProduct($sku)
     {
      $this->productModel = $this->productRepository->get($sku);
      }

      public function getValue($attributeCode)
      {
       if ($this->productModel !== null) {
        return $this->productModel->getCustomAttribute($attributeCode)- 
        >getValue();
        }
        return null;
        }
        }
        ?>
```

3. Please check this template PHTML file where i am calling the functions by passing the arguments of sku and attribute code:

   ```
    <?php

   /** @var \OX\PrintSampleContent\Block\Template $block
   *  @var \Magento\Framework\Escaper $escaper
   */
    $block->setProduct('MP12');
    $label = $block->getLabel('description');
    $value = $block->getValue('description');
    ?>
    <div class="container attribute-container">
    <div class="attribute-row">
       <div class="col-12">
           <div class="attribute-label"><?=$escaper->escapeHtml("MP12")? 
        >
               <span style="color #4361ee;">Attribute Value</span>
           </div>
           <div class="attribute-label"><?=$escaper->escapeHtml($label)? 
           >
               <span style="color: #4361ee;">Attribute Value</span>
           </div>
           <div class="attribute-label"><?=$value?></div>
           </div>
           </div>
           </div>
   ```
4. Please do not mind the alignment of the code as there is some issue with this editor could not make this code alignment for this answer work properly but it will work once you use it in your module.

If this post helped you , please do give me a like as this helps me answer more , and please do comment if any help is needed regarding this.Thanks.

Output screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Also, what is the purpose of the value "4" for this line of code "$attribute = $this->attributeRepository->get("4", 
        $attributeCode);"

Comment: That is the entity type code , the value 4 is of entity = catalog_product , you can check these numbers in the table entity_type where all 6 will be present.

Comment: Thank you very much for clarifying that!